# Event on appended text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was javascript to dynamically add some content, my javascript is like:

```
document.getElementById("lines").innerHTML += some_of_my_data +"</br>;
```

How can I create a mouseover event, different on each row?

Comment: Hi. We would like to help you, but this questions needs to be updated to better explain what you want. Please check the guidelines on how to ask a question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please put a little information in the question, otherwise it's close to impossible to answer.

But some notes:

You don't seem to be closing the quotes on your text (after `</br>`).

Also `</br>` should be `<br>`

Here I'm just guessing but you're selecting by id and the id is called `lines` which suggests many, maybe you're using the id `lines` multiple times? That would be incorrect and might be what's not working.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) how to get element's of the same class.

Also for mouse over events, take a looks at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903312/463065).